# Pandas rolling mean with offset by (not continuously available) date

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, rolling-computation

given the following example table

| Index | Date | Weekday | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/12/2022 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 06/12/2022 | 3 | 20 |
| 3 | 07/12/2022 | 4 | 40 |
| 4 | 09/12/2022 | 6 | 10 |
| 5 | 10/12/2022 | 7 | 60 |
| 6 | 11/12/2022 | 1 | 30 |
| 7 | 12/12/2022 | 2 | 40 |
| 8 | 13/12/2022 | 3 | 50 |
| 9 | 14/12/2022 | 4 | 60 |
| 10 | 16/12/2022 | 6 | 20 |
| 11 | 17/12/2022 | 7 | 50 |
| 12 | 18/12/2022 | 1 | 10 |
| 13 | 20/12/2022 | 3 | 20 |
| 14 | 21/12/2022 | 4 | 10 |
| 15 | 22/12/2022 | 5 | 40 |

I want to calculate a rolling average of the last three observations (at least) a week ago. I cannot use .shift as some dates are randomly missing, and .shift would therefore not produce a reliable output.

Desired output example for last three rows in the example dataset:

`Index 13: Avg of indices 8, 7, 6 = (30+40+50) / 3 = 40`

`Index 14: Avg of indices 9, 8, 7 = (40+50+60) / 3 = 50`

`Index 15: Avg of indices 9, 8, 7 = (40+50+60) / 3 = 50`

What would be a working solution for this? Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOSTLY inspired from @Aidis you could, make his solution an apply:

```
df['mean']=df.apply(lambda y:  df["Value"][df['Date'] <= y['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, "W")].tail(3).mean(), axis=1)
```

or spliting the data at each call which may run faster if you have lots of data (to be tested):

```
df['mean']=df.apply(lambda y:  df.loc[:y.name, "Value"][ df.loc[:y.name,'Date'] <= y['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, "W")].tail(3).mean(), axis=1)
```

which returns:

```
    Index       Date  Weekday  Value       mean
0       1 2022-12-05        2     10        NaN
1       2 2022-12-06        3     20        NaN
2       3 2022-12-07        4     40        NaN
3       4 2022-12-09        6     10        NaN
4       5 2022-12-10        7     60        NaN
5       6 2022-12-11        1     30        NaN
6       7 2022-12-12        2     40  10.000000
7       8 2022-12-13        3     50  15.000000
8       9 2022-12-14        4     60  23.333333
9      10 2022-12-16        6     20  23.333333
10     11 2022-12-17        7     50  36.666667
11     12 2022-12-18        1     10  33.333333
12     13 2022-12-20        3     20  40.000000
13     14 2022-12-21        4     10  50.000000
14     15 2022-12-22        5     40  50.000000
```

Comment: I have a big data set and did some (not so) quick speed test - both options are not too different regarding speed.


First one: 1min 7s ± 16.2 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 5 loops each)
Second one: 1min ± 5.31 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 5 loops each)

Thank you!

Comment: if you can add libs maybe try pandarallel: https://mathdatasimplified.com/2022/12/09/pandarallel-a-simple-tool-to-parallelize-pandas-operations/

Comment: libs as in imported libraries? also thanks for pandarallel, didn't know it.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for this ugly code. But it seems to work:

```
df = df.set_index("Index")
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype("datetime64")
for id in df.index:
    dfs = df.loc[:id]
    mean = dfs["Value"][dfs['Date'] <= dfs.iloc[-1]['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, "W")].tail(3).mean()
    print(id, mean)
```

Result:

```
1 nan
2 10.0
3 15.0
4 23.333333333333332
5 23.333333333333332
6 36.666666666666664
7 33.333333333333336
8 33.333333333333336
9 33.333333333333336
10 33.333333333333336
11 33.333333333333336
12 33.333333333333336
13 40.0
14 50.0
15 50.0
```